# Is there a way to allow blank data for Django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a products model that I want to have optional fields that are not required by the user
whenever i try to input empty data it throws an error 400 back to the user meaning the serialized data is not valid

views.py

```
def products(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        products = Product.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.initial_data['user'] = request.user.pk
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    discount = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 5):

The way DRF understands what field is required is by looking at your model field's option called `null` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#null)).

If `null=True`, DRF will handle this field as not required

If you do not want to set this option in your model's class, you can make it work in serializer class via `required` [option](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required), e.g.

```py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializer.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specifying fields explicitly and add `required=false` like this :

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # We make the description field empty
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'user' , 'shop' ...] # Each field you want in the response.
        # Or you can use extra_kwargs since DRF 3.12.x
        extra_kwargs = {"description": {"required": False, "allow_null": True}}
```